# How to import from a subdirectory in Colab

Tags: python, import, google-colaboratory

In my python project folder on my PC, I have sub-folders containing modules that are imported. e.g. There is a /util subfolder with a file myUtil.py.

A py file in the main project folder has:

```
from util.myUtil import func1
```

How can I replicate this when uploaded to Colab? i.e. What was my main py file is now the notebook, and I want to type the above 'from' statement into the notebook. However, nothing I do can get it to find the file in the subfolder. The import fails with:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'
```

I have uploaded the util directory to my Google Drive, and I have executed "%cd" to set my working directory to the directory where the notebook is located, but still no luck.

Thanks for any help.

Julian

Answer (score 0):

```
# Mount Driver
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Insert the directory
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/content/drive/MyDrive/MyPath...') # Insert your complete path here, use \ if you have spaces in the path name
```